# Exception occurred loading manifest from file MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll

Tags: windows, clickonce

I've visited just about every SO post on this error and can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have a ClickOnce application that I am using internally at my company, and the installer works on several different machines, but not one of my user's. I'm wondering if it's maybe a permissions issue or something, because the errors don't really make sense considering it installs fine for everyone else. Please let me know your thoughts. Error file below (some parts removed for privacy):

```
    Windows             : 10.0.19044.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    clr.dll             : 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Parsing Helper.application, Version=1.0.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : Parsing Helper.exe, Version=1.0.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of I:\..\Parsing Helper.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
        + File MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll is not a valid Portable Executable (PE) file.
        + PE file does not have enough data.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [8/18/2022 3:11:50 PM] : Activation of I:\..\Parsing Helper.application has started.
    * [8/18/2022 3:11:52 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [8/18/2022 3:11:52 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [8/18/2022 3:11:54 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [8/18/2022 3:11:56 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [8/18/2022 3:11:56 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [8/18/2022 3:12:32 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.IOException
        - File MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll is not a valid Portable Executable (PE) file.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ConstructFromFile(String filePath, Boolean partialConstruct)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.IOException
        - PE file does not have enough data.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.PEComponent.ReadData(FileStream file, Int64 position, Type dataType)
            at System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ResourceDirectoryEntry..ctor(FileStream file, Int64 address)
            at System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ResourceDirectory..ctor(ResourceSection resourceSection, FileStream file, Int64 rootResourceAddress, Int64 resourceAddress, Int64 addressDelta, Boolean partialConstruct)
            at System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ResourceSection..ctor(FileStream file, SectionHeader sectionHeader, Boolean partialConstruct)
            at System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ConstructPEImage(FileStream file, Boolean partialConstruct)
            at System.Deployment.Application.PEStream.ConstructFromFile(String filePath, Boolean partialConstruct)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. It had nothing to do with MaterialDesignThemes specifically, it was that nothing was able to be written to the user's drive because of a permissions issue. I solved it by deselecting the "Read-only" checkbox on a subfolder's properties that the app eventually installs in:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Apps`